# Getting Short code SMS texts to US VoIP number from Panama

Tags: cellphones

I am a non-techie, and I can't fix this myself. I use Amazon pharmacy for getting my prescriptions and they are using short texts to verify my phone number, which, of course, isn't working. Are there companies that do VOIP or some other protocol that would let me have a US number that DOES register for short texts?

Comment: Can't you just disable Two Step Verification ? https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=G3PWZPU52FKN7PW4

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your are in the US? with a US cellphone number from Panama?

Comment: Related questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142673/how-can-i-receive-sms-including-short-codes-while-in-france and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129356/voip-providers-that-provide-support-to-receiving-sms-from-short-codes?rq=1

Comment: I am in Panama with a VOIP number for the US. Amazon Pharmacy requires a US number to be able to contact me with. They cannot use my Panama number and... the VOIP I have doesn't wotk with short code texts.

Comment: I am trying to Change my listed number with Amazon to the US  VOIP instead of my Panama number. I can't disable 2 step verification for this. They require confirmation with a short code.

Comment: 1. Isn't there an option to get a call instead of the short text?
2. Does Amazon really ship prescriptions outside the US?

Comment: No there is no option for sending to email or call for Rx. And no, they do not ship to Panama. I have a forwarder.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Google Voice, it works with >95% of the services I've tried, and is free. However you do need a US phone number in addition to Google Voice.

Another solution is Google Fi, but it's not free.

Comment: I need Google Voice to BE my US number. That used to work - that they gave you a new number. Not anymore, I guess?

Comment: @CelesteMendelsohn I use my Google voice number for short messages from CVS pharmacy and Walgreens pharmacy that works on my side